# rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_point,AFTER_SYNC?

Tags: mysql, replication

The master waits for slave acknowledgment of transaction receipt after the sync. Upon receiving acknowledgment, the master commits the transaction to the storage engine and returns a result to the client.I want know when the slaves commit ?

Answer (score 0):

The slaves commit whenever they get around to it, which can be within a matter of milliseconds, but can also take a substantial amount of time if the slave is lagging, because it's overloaded or underpowered, or because a process has obtained locks on the slave that cause the updates to wait for the locks.

Semi-synchronous replication only guarantees that no transaction is **lost** by making sure that at least one slave has saved -- not executed -- a copy of the the transaction.

The data is safe from any single-failure loss once the replication `IO_THREAD` on any slave has receive and written the replication event to its relay log on disk, and confirmed this fact back to the master server.

> The slave acknowledges receipt of a transaction's events only after the events have been written to its relay log and flushed to disk.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-semisync.html

The slave `SQL_THREAD` reads the events that the `IO_THREAD` has written to the relay log and applies them to the slave's data set, but this part is a fully-asynchronous process that provides no feedback towards the semi-sync logic.

If you need the slaves to be immediately in sync for read queries of data that has just been written to the master, native replication -- neither asynchronous (conventional) nor semi-sync provides that.  If that is what you require, you need [Galera Replication Provider](http://galeracluster.com), which makes replication truly synchronous (and makes all the servers in the cluster into writable masters).

Comment: So,the slave will commit the transcation after sync log, do not wait the master commit?